# How to use reindex to fill in missing timesteps?

Tags: pandas

I'm trying to test the example given in the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) that fills in missing timesteps

```
date_index = pd.date_range('1/1/2010', periods=6, freq='D')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"prices": [100, 101, np.nan, 100, 89, 88]}, index=date_index)
date_index2 = pd.date_range('12/29/2009', periods=10, freq='D')

#show how many rows are in the fragmented dataframe
print(df2.shape)
df2.reindex(date_index2)

#show how many rows after reindexing
print(df2.shape)
```

But running this code shows that no rows were added. What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`reindex` does not work inplace by default. You can do

```
print(df2.shape)

# assign back
df2 = df2.reindex(date_index2)
print(df2.shape)
```

Output:

```
(6, 1)
(10, 1)
```